# What is the best search solution for PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'm looking for the best solution to perform PHP MYSQL searching but I don't want to use Sphinx, I'm using Nginx under Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Solr : http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Choosing a search solution depends on a few things like:

1. Amount of data
2. Complexity of that data
3. How often will you use search?
4. How advanced will those searched be?

There are others like Lucene: http://lucene.apache.org/

Comment: i want to performe advanced and smart search i want to use 4 databases atleast, i have big data and i want fast results !

Comment: The technologies mentioned like Solr and Lucene are good enough.